# Cannot assign to property in protocol - Swift compiler error

Tags: ios, swift

I'm banging my head against the wall with the following code in Swift. I've defined a simple protocol:

```
protocol Nameable {
    var name : String { get set }
}
```

and implemented that with:

```
class NameableImpl : Nameable {
    var name : String = ""
}
```

and then I have the following method in another file (don't ask me why):

```
func nameNameable( nameable: Nameable, name: String ) {
    nameable.name = name
}
```

The problem is that the compiler gives the following error for the property assignment in this method:

> **cannot assign to 'name' in 'nameable'**

I can't see what I'm doing wrong... The following code compiles fine:

```
var nameable : Nameable = NameableImpl()
nameable.name = "John"
```

I'm sure it's something simple I've overlooked - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 115):

@matt's anwer is correct.

Another solution is to declare `Nameable` as a [`class` only protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_422).

```
protocol Nameable: class {
//               ^^^^^^^ 
    var name : String { get set }
}
```

I think, this solution is more suitable for this case. Because `nameNameable` is useless unless `nameable` is a instance of `class`.

Comment: My appreciation for Swift just grew bigger because of this.

Comment: This +10000. I was having major issues implementing a protocol and extensions that involved a struct property, and was unable to mutate it without all sorts of headaches, but adding `class` solved everything.

Comment: Why does this work, but not `protocol Nameable where Self : UIView` (assuming you just wanted views to inherit this protocol). UIView is a class, but it won't actually get rid of his error.

Comment: In Swift 4+ one should use `protocol Nameable: AnyObject` instead

Answer (score 45):

It's because, Nameable being a protocol, Swift doesn't know what *kind* (flavor) of object your function's incoming Nameable is. It might be a class instance, sure - but it might be a struct instance. And you *can't assign to a property of a constant struct*, as the following example demonstrates:

```
struct NameableStruct : Nameable {
    var name : String = ""
}
let ns = NameableStruct(name:"one")
ns.name = "two" // can't assign
```

Well, by default, an incoming function parameter *is* a constant - it is exactly as if you had said `let` in your function declaration before you said `nameable`.

The solution is to make this parameter *not* be a constant:

```
func nameNameable(var nameable: Nameable, name: String ) {
                  ^^^
```

**NOTE** Later versions of Swift have abolished the `var` function parameter notation, so you'd accomplish the same thing by assigning the constant to a variable:

```
protocol Nameable {
    var name : String { get set }
}
func nameNameable(nameable: Nameable, name: String) {
    var nameable = nameable // can't compile without this line
    nameable.name = name
}
```

Comment: tl;dr change "let myProtocolConformingItem" to "var myProtocolConformingItem"

Comment: @matt While this proposal/solution definitely works and is currently even proposed by the compiler, do you consider it being a code smell?

Comment: i am getting error `use of undeclared type of nameable `

Comment: @Jack that was years ago! My answer isn't valid Swift syntax nowadays

Comment: @Jack added a modernized version of the same answer

Answer (score 0):

Here, i written some code, that might give some idea on Associated generic type Usage:

```
protocol NumaricType 
{
   typealias elementType
   func plus(lhs : elementType, _ rhs : elementType) -> elementType
   func minus(lhs : elementType, _ rhs : elementType) -> elementType
}

struct Arthamatic :NumaricType {

func addMethod(element1 :Int, element2 :Int) -> Int {
   return plus(element1, element2)
}
func minusMethod(ele1 :Int, ele2 :Int) -> Int {
    return minus(ele1, ele2)
}
typealias elementType = Int

func plus(lhs: elementType,  _ rhs: elementType) -> elementType {
    return lhs + rhs
}
func minus(lhs: elementType, _ rhs: elementType) -> elementType {
    return lhs - rhs
 }
}
 **Output:**
let obj =  Arthamatic().addMethod(34, element2: 45) // 79
```