# Protocol delegation

Tags: swift, protocols

Xcode is really giving me a hard time on this one. Any idea why I'm receiving this following error?

**"Cannot assign to property: 'containerChild' is a 'let' constant"**

```
protocol AlarmViewControllerDelegate {
    var rootController: AlarmViewController? { get set }
}
```

The following prepareForSegue function is in AlarmViewController.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let containerChild = segue.destination as? AlarmViewControllerDelegate {
        containerChild.rootController = self
    }
}
```

I've never encountered this issue with similar protocols. I'm not trying to set a new value to the let constant?

Comment: Define a *class protocol,* as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27241632/1187415 to the duplicate.